# Xcode codesign dialog hangs

Tags: xcode, codesign

When uploading my app to the store from Xcode 7.1, I get this dialog:
[image: codesign dialog]

Clicking "Always Allow" or "Allow" has no effect. Only "Deny" actually works, but of course I don't want to do that.

Anyone have this problem? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Apparently El Capitan includes measures to prevent 3rd party apps from sending virtual mouse clicks to Keychain Access dialogs. I learned this [from here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/84098#83900).

I was running MagicPrefs for extra mouse gestures. I just had to quit MagicPrefs, and then I was able to click these buttons.